# iOS: Pull down to see logo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, graphical-logo

Often in iOS apps you find a company logo when you pull down instead of the usual "Pull to refresh" feature. I've Googled quite a lot, but it seems nobody has really wanted to do this. How would a custom logo when you pull down on a view be implemented?

Comment: can you give an example of an app that does this? Or a picture? It's possible that they have the background of their navigation controller set to a graphic of their logo. I've done that before so you can see the company logo during a flip transition

Comment: @DavidHope You can't take a screenshot when pulling up/down, but apps like [Day One](http://dayoneapp.com/) have a logo appear when you pull up (at the bottom of the view). I don't care if it's up or down as long as I can get the logo somewhere.

Comment: add the logo image and make the delegate method and CUSTOMIZE/ADD to th "pull to refresh" file.

Comment: @Beakr You can, just don't let go of the screen. Without looking at what you're referring to, I imagine they are just setting the logo as the `tableHeaderView` property of a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2):

You could place a UIImageView above the origin of the scrollView's contentView.

i.e.

```
UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100)];
logoView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];

[scrollView.contentView addSubView:logoView];
```

Hmm... not 100% certain if this will work as I expect without testing?

If this doesn't work then it will just put the logoView at the top of the scrollView. Let me know and I'll try again :D

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Is it not pulling down correctly?

Comment: Actually, I think it's something wrong with the scroll view. :P

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add your logo image as a subview into the refresh control (and remove/hide the default)

See my tutorial here for implementing Custom Pull to Refresh Controls in Objective-C and Swift: http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

And checkout the `setupRefreshControl` method for how it's put together.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have further questions!